# Let $G'$ be the commutator subgroup of $G$. Find the order of quotient group $G/G'$

Tags: abstract-algebra

Let $G'$ be the commutator subgroup of $G$. Find the order of quotient group $G/G'$

I start with...

Let $H=G'$, then if we have $aH,bH\in G/H$, consider their product, $abH$ since $[b^{-1},a^{-1}]\in H$, we have $(aH)(bH)=abH=abb^{-1}a^{-1}baH=baH=(bH)(aH)$. This $G/H$ is abelian. Then if apply first theorem of isomorphism we have that $G'$ with $ker K$ impplies that $|ϕG|=[G:ker ϕ ]=|G|/|ker ϕ |$ but $G/ker⁡ϕ≅ϕG$, then $|G'|<|G|$. Am I ok?

Comment: Perhaps you could edit your question to make it clearer?  What is $H$? (Is it $G'$?  Also, what exactly is the statement you are trying to prove about $G/G'$?

Comment: it can change depending on the group $G$

Comment: I try to find the order of $G/G'$, and $H=G'$ @BobbyGrizzard

Comment: I know that it can be change @CarryonSmiling but I want to know if $|G/G'|<|G|$ or $|G/G'|>|G|$ or $|G/G'|=|G|$ I miss some steps

Comment: Let $G$ be a finite abelian group; then $G'=\{1\}$, so the order of $G/G'$ is the same as the order of $G$, which can be anything. If $G$ is a finite simple non abelian group, then $G'=G$, so your conjecture about $|G'|<|G|$ is wrong.

Comment: Any quotient of $G$ has order less than or equal to the order of $G$.  The orders are equal if and only if the group you're modding out by is trivial.  Nothing special about commutators.

Comment: @egreg why $G'=\{1\}$??

Comment: @Joe If $G$ is abelian, any two elements have commutator equal to $1$

Comment: Thank you very much!!! @egreg